# Getting an error while importing Loader from 'react-loader-spinner'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The error I'm getting:

```
ERROR in ./src/components/Loading.jsx 9:33-39

export 'default' (imported as 'Loader') was not found in 'react-loader-spinner' (possible exports: Audio, BallTriangle, Bars, Circles, CradleLoader, Grid, Hearts, MutatingDots, Oval, Plane, Puff, RevolvingDot, Rings, TailSpin, ThreeDots, Triangle, Watch)
```

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Loader from 'react-loader-spinner';

export const Loading = () => (
  <div className="flex justify-center items-center ">
    <Loader type="Puff" color="#00BFFF" height={550} width={80} />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loader-spinner check their documentation. the available spinnerTypes are provided there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to import that specific loader you want, as there are many of them that `react-loader-spinner` exports. For example the code below  is for [Rings](https://mhnpd.github.io/react-loader-spinner/rings) loader.

> All loader types are [here](https://mhnpd.github.io/react-loader-spinner/) on the official documentation.

```js
import { Rings } from 'react-loader-spinner';

export const Loading = () => (
  <div className="flex justify-center items-center ">
    <Rings color="#00BFFF" height={80} width={80} />
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 7):

`react-loader-spinner` exports various loaders and you can use those loaders directly. And if you want to import all the loaders and use them. You can do it like this.

```
import * as Loader from "react-loader-spinner";

function App() {
  return <Loader.TailSpin />;
}
```

or

```
import {TailSpin} from "react-loader-spinner";

function App() {
  return <TailSpin />;
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-herschel-652kq?file=/src/index.js:70-168

Answer (score 0):

**You can import specific one from react-loader-spinner**

```
import React from 'react'
import {Triangle} from 'react-loader-spinner'
const Loading = () => {
  return (
    <div className='flex justify-center items-center'>
        <Triangle type='Puff' color='#00BFFF' height={550} width={80} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Loading
```

https://mhnpd.github.io/react-loader-spinner/ **Here you can find many examples of Loaders**

Answer (score 0):

make sure use the correct method of import and Export ,It Normally occurs because false Way of importing and exporting

Use this for Making and Importing the Loader
Here we are targeting the specific loader from react-loader-spinner

```
import React from 'react';
import { Rings } from 'react-loader-spinner';
export const Loading = () => (
  <div>
    <Rings color="#00BFFF" height={80} width={80} />
  </div>
);
```

See carefully that we don't use default Here so to import in main component

```
import {Loading}  from './Loading.jsx';
```